# Analytic continuation of the prime zeta function

Tags: special-functions, number-theory

I want to plot the real part of the [prime zeta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeZetaFunction.html) over the imaginary axis. This should be doable since the prime zeta function has an analytic continuation up to the imaginary axis. However, Mathematica doesn't seem to know about it.

```
Plot[Re[PrimeZetaP[I x]], {x, 0, 10}]
```

just gives an empty plot, and

```
x = 1
Re[PrimeZetaP[I x]]
x =.
```

doesn't evaluate.

Is there some trick, or the explicit form of the analytic continuation? I can't find it.

Comment: [The documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrimeZetaP.html) says that this analytic continuation is defined only for $0<\text{Re}(s)\le1$. So you cannot use it for $\text{Re}(s)=0$ as in your example. Numerical experimentation indicates that the imaginary part of the function diverges as the real part of the argument approaches zero.

Comment: Based on the results of [Landau and Walfisz](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF03014596), I don't think you'd have much luck doing what you want.

Comment: Maybe: `P[s_, m_] := Sum[MoebiusMu[k]/k*Log[Zeta[k*s]], {k, 1, m}]; Plot[Re[P[I x, 25]], {x, 0, 10}]` ?